# Switching 12V vehicle headlights with Arduino / Mosfet combination

Tags: arduino, mosfet, relay, automotive, 12v

Ground level noob here, started to tinker with electronics at the beginning of this year after I couldn't get any electronics shop in my town replace my bike's gauge cluster SMD LEDs.

I learned few things last few weeks and now I'm at the mosfet stage. I want to control the headlight with mosfet and I managed to assemble a code for Arduino IDE that controls the LED the way I want, tested the 12V 25W LED bulb on my desk with bench power supply and Arduino hooked to buck converter, with the LED bulb controlled with a breadboard size pushbutton and a mosfet. I bought the wrong (high Rds, not logic level) nMOS at first, but learned to read some specs and got IRL2203 that operates the light and keeps cool with no heatsink.

The challenge is how to install it in the vehicle while keeping the original controls intact and without adding anything extra. I am going thru YouTube vids on schematics and trying to figure out where in the "headlight circuit" should I tap in with the Arduino and mosfet. One thing that kind of worries me now, I'm starting to think I planned this wrong going with the nMOS and all, I highlighted all the headlight-relay wires and it seems that pMOS would be the correct choice to tap into these wires, and accessing ground wires for nMOS would be too challenging?

As I'm not well versed in these, please let me know what can I do here.

One idea I had was completely remove headlights from the circuit, from the relay and everything, and run a separate circuit from headlight fuse? Just thinking out loud :D Let me know how would I go about solving this, cheers

[image]

Comment: Arduino, MOSFET, motorcycle and headlights are words that do not go together well. Your headlights should be considered safety critical system. Please be careful.

Comment: Be advised, if your headlights turned out later to be even a factor in a car crash, your insurance would likely be void for using non/substandard parts.

Answer (score 1):

I would say yes to your last thought.

[image]

Just keep those two separated from the whole circuit and hook your arduino and mosfet there. Keep the connections from the rest of the circuitry as little as possible.

For example you can take the output from this "LIGHNING SWITCH" and use it as an input to your arduino. When you press the switch, the arduino will sense it, the lights will turn on.

[image]

Something like this will do the trick:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJhh7V.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**EDIT**

Regarding the N-mos, P-mos, this is a picture of my noted regarding those:

[image]

N-mosfets have lower internal resistance (Rin) (look in [mouser.com for the  mosfets](https://gr.mouser.com/Semiconductors/Discrete-Semiconductors/Transistors/MOSFET/_/N-ax1sf), play with the N/P- chanel filters and check the Rin differences between the N channel and P-channel (Ignore the NPN, PNP etc options)

N-channel mosfets are easier to use when put on the low side (since you control Vgs, and you have a steady GND at source, you can play with the V at the gate. (This is why i have an "L" box on my notes, its  where i put the "Load").

Also, enhancement type means it turns on when the Vgs is (lets say for logic mosfets) 5[V] or more. Depletion type means the fet turns on when Vgs is 0[V] or less.

Having said that, if you check on mouser, P-channels have easily 10 ohms of Rin (huge huge!) N-ch can easily have 0.009Ohms of internal R.

Also, if you check on Mouser the "Depletion type", you will notice that there are no P-channel mosfets with Depletion type. That is, becouse they are expensive to manufacture, they have higher Rin, no one wants them.

This leaves you with enhancement type P-channel mosfet. So, If you want to power your bulb with 12V, you put it on the low side, how will you turn it on? you need Vgs = 5V, you will need another supply of 12+5=17V, like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdozHu.png)</sup>

That is why, it ususally is a bad idea to use a P-ch. Only when you really need a device (load) to be connected to the GND directly, you would put a P-ch there (like if you wanted to power a computer, motherboard, MCU etc)

Comment: Yeah the more I dig into these things the more I appreciate how complex these things are, and how much thought and planning went into it - and how far I am from that methodical approach :D separating the circuit for headlights is good approach - what would be the problem if I went with pMos, logic level?

Comment: Hmm let me edit the answer to include what happens with pmos

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the detailed explanation! I'm looking at the wiring diagram...and the idea of separating headlights, what about actually tapping into headlight wires, just before the bulb connectors? Unplug the headlight relay and run two nMos from the headlight grounds?

Comment: something like this - https://i.imgur.com/gndCPCU.jpg

Comment: Bad idea to interrupt the grounds. By doing this you open up the possibility of ‘sneak circuits’ ie paths that aren’t obvious. The positive side is switched for a reason.  I’d suggest using automotive relays and using small mosfets to drive the coils. One thing to note - the fuses protect the wire. If you short your average piece of wire across your battery (not suggested you do this) the wire will melt and smoke. You don’t want this to happen. So use a fuse or ensure your power is via a fuse and the wire is rated for the fuse current.

Comment: @Kartman the more you know! Thanks for the heads up, yeah my idea of tapping into the back of the bulbs is a total hack approach. Damn. On the vehicle there are "old school" relays from the OEM specs 20 year old things, is there perhaps a newer "faster" relay to replace these OEM units - is it ludicrous to think about solid state relays instead of "common ones" - or do you just suggest pinging the existing relays with mosfet arduino combination? It does sound like the simplest approach, but for whatever reason I always think of relays as "slow"...but then again I'm a newb :D

Comment: Slow? Do you want to run pwm in order to vary the brightness or just turn the headlights on and off? Mechanical relays are hard to kill, mosfets in the other hand need protection. Infineon have some nice high side switches that might suit. They even have four of them on an Arduino like board. That would take care of the evil you face.

Comment: @Kartman I will look into the high side switches then, seems like isolated breadboard tests and actual 12V vehicle circuits are two different things :D My main concern is keeping the functionality the same - for example the Passing switch - it triggers the high beam light as long as you keep it pressed. If I want to have this function controlled by Arduino, how would I make use of 12V signal there...or perhaps another idea would be to rewire that button so it's connected straight to Arduino, remove it from the original 12V loom. I got a lot of homework to do :)

Comment: If all you want to do is turn the headlights on and off, use relays. For the passing switch - relay. The relay contacts across the switch. Have the Arduino control the relay via a small low side logic level mosfet. In my part of town we have a number of auto dismantlers - we pay $2 to get in. Exit with a pocketful of bolts, lamps, fuses and for you, some relays.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121311/discussion-between-varonne-and-kartman).